# Is there a shortcut to navigate to next application on the same desktop on mac os?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I have set up 4 desktops on my mac, and on each desktop I have several applications opening. So when I'm on one desktop, and I just want to cycle through all the applications opening at current desktop. alt + tab doesn't fullfill:

1. it switches between applications of all desktop
2. it "switches", if you just alt + tab once, you're going to switch back to last application

Instead of popup a little window with icons of all application like when you press alt + tab, I want it directly bring the next application window to the top of current desktop. It's something like alt + esc on windows.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click alt+tab quick enough it does not present the small selection screen, but it will span across all open applications on all desktops. Otherwise there isn't anything built-in to OS X to do what you're looking for.

The next closest thing is Expose (Now called Mission Control). You can configure that in the System Preferences panel. This will present you the ability to see all open Applications, Application Windows or the Desktop.